# Declaring that a type can not be null

Tags: java, spring, validation, null, annotations

I am using [Spring's Bean validation](http://java.dzone.com/articles/method-validation-spring-31) to handle `null` parameters and return values in method declarations.

Example:

```
@Validated
public interface MyService {
    @NotNull User createNewUser(@NotNull Username username, @NotNull Password password);
}
```

where `Username` and `Password` are just wrapers of username and password Strings, `User` is a class representing a user's account, and `@NotNull` is `javax.validation.constraints.NotNull`.

Actually, `MyService` has more methods and there are other classes that I decided to declare their parameters and return types with `@NotNull` like the example above. But then I think my code is far from elegant as it is full of boilerplate `@NotNull` declarations.

So I think it would be great if I can  do this,

```
@NotNull
public class Username {...}

@NotNull
public class User {...}

@NotNull
public class Password {...}
```

**And expect that a variable of type `Username`, `Password`, `User`, etc. can not be `null`, so that I don't have to repeatedly precedes those variables with `@NotNull` anywhere else.** (Actully, the `@NotNull` annotation is not allowed to use with a class declaration)

Is it possible to acheive that in some ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Annotations like this ends up having a proxy around the annotated method. Since you want to make a null-check, you won't be able to proxy the object that is not even created :) So I think all you can do is defining a proxy with Spring AOP around all methods that use *Username* or *Password* as parameter. See the ***args*** option in [Spring doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html). 
You'll might end up with something like this (haven't tested):

```
<aop:config>
  <aop:aspect id="nullValidation" ref="nullValidatorAspect">
    <aop:around pointcut="args(foo.bar.Username,..)" method="validateNull"/>
    <aop:around pointcut="args(foo.bar.Password,..)" method="validateNull"/>
  </aop:aspect>
</aop:config>
```

And your *NullValidatorAspect* class will have a method something like this. This part is tricky, because since you receive nulls you cannot use *instanceof* to validate the type of the parameter. So you either validate all parameters against null:

```
public Object validateNull(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) {
  Object[] args = pjp.getArgs(); 
  for ( Object arg : args ) {
     //not null validation
  }
  pjp.proceed();
}
```

...or you dig deeper and apply some logic around the method signature (like stepping parallelly on the argument array with the parameter types array)

```
final MethodSignature methodSignature = (MethodSignature)pjp.getSignature();
Method method = methodSignature.getMethod();
Class<?>[] paramTypes = method.getParameterTypes());
```

Hope this helps, 
Gergely